# How to build an aggregate table based on the another shiny table?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to have a output table in the UI that has a conditional column sum based on the text of "Column 3".

Here is my example code:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
ui=pageWithSidebar(headerPanel("Adding entries to table"),
                 sidebarPanel(textInput("text1", "Column 1", "66"),
                              textInput("text2", "Column 2", "100"),
                              textInput("text3", "Column 3", "Tony"),
                              actionButton("update", "Update Table")),
                 mainPanel(tableOutput("table1"))),
server=function(input, output, session) {
values <- reactiveValues()
values$df <- data.frame(Column3 = character(), 
                        Column1 = numeric(0), 
                        Column2 = numeric(0),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
newEntry <- observe({
  if(input$update > 0) {
    newLine <- isolate(c(input$text3, input$text1, input$text2))
    isolate(values$df[nrow(values$df) + 1,] <- c(input$text3, 
input$text1, input$text2))
  }
})
output$table1 <- renderTable({values$df})
}))
```

If you click on the "Update Table" button twice, the output table that I would like to see it is:

```
`1    Tony    132    200`
```

The names in "Column 3" will be different depends on the input value from the sidebar. The output table should observe that, and then return all the names with sum of "Column 1" and sum of "Column 2" under that name.

I tried to create a new data frame using the aggregate function on the `values$df`, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are aiming for. I have added appropriate comments in the code for you to understand. Hope it helps!

```
library(shiny)
    runApp(list(
      ui=pageWithSidebar(headerPanel("Adding entries to table"),
                         sidebarPanel(textInput("text1", "Column 1", "66"),
                                      textInput("text2", "Column 2", "100"),
                                      textInput("text3", "Column 3", "Tony"),
                                      actionButton("update", "Update Table")),
                         mainPanel(tableOutput("table1"))),
      server=function(input, output, session) {
        values <- reactiveValues()
        values$df <- data.frame(Column3 = character(), 
                                Column1 = numeric(0), 
                                Column2 = numeric(0),
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        observeEvent(input$update,{
          # if(input$update > 0) {#This is not required as this observeEvent will only be triggered when we click 'update' button 
            newLine <- isolate(c(input$text3, input$text1, input$text2))
            #If any column 3 has already been updated, just add the other columns
            if(any(values$df$Column3 == input$text3))
            {
              #Get the row where there is match in the Column3
              matchRow = which(values$df$Column3 == input$text3)
              #Just add the values in column2 and column3 with input values
              values$df$Column1[matchRow] <- as.numeric(values$df$Column1[matchRow])+as.numeric(input$text1)
              values$df$Column2[matchRow] <- as.numeric(values$df$Column2[matchRow])+as.numeric(input$text2)

            }else{#Just add the new rows

              isolate(values$df[nrow(values$df) + 1,] <- c(input$text3, 
                                                           input$text1, input$text2))
            }
          # }
        })
        output$table1 <- renderTable({values$df})
      }))
```